# Display images as a form element in a webform

Tags: 8, webforms

The goal is quite simple – I'm looking for a way to display an image in a webform.
By that I mean the image would part of the webform as a complement to a question (example: "what color is the car in this picture").

If possible it'd be great if the user could to upload the images when administrating the webform elements, and also if they were their own element that would be awesome (but even adding them to the descriptions of the question-elements themselves *could* work as well).

**So basically, how can I setup a "display custom image in the webform"-element?**

I've tried searching for a solution but all my results are about how to add an image upload field, which is quite the opposite of what I'm looking for.

Grateful for any help I could get on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install the [IMCE module](https://www.drupal.org/project/imce) and set up the right permissions, users can upload and insert images into a webform.

Another option is to change the Webform module's default HTML Editor to use a Text format which supports inline images. You would do this by going to Webform > Configuration > Elements ( (/admin/structure/webform/config/elements)

Comment: Brilliant – I didn't know that Media Library could be [added to CKEditor](https://drudesk.com/blog/media-library-drupal-8-embed-button) as well, so after adding that to the text format I have all the functionality I need without any additional modules, thank you for the help!